# Running a Simulation n times and storing the values in a matrix and taking average of values

Tags: r, dataframe, optimization, statistics, data-modeling

I am working on a simulation for a pandemic data, I calculated MLE, which has a values for example 0.99. This is for SEIR Modelling, so I have a dataframe for S,E,I and R. Now I am running simulation for the same, but I want to replicate the simulation 100 times and then consider the average.

My simulation code, is the following.

```
### Pre-define VALUES
# 50 days
sumofnew_infec<-rep(0,50)
Snew<-rep(0,50)
Enew<-rep(0,50)
Inew<-rep(0,50)
Rnew<-rep(0,50)
Snew[1]<-Current_dayStats$St[1]
Inew[1]<-Current_dayStats$It[1]
Enew[1]<-Current_dayStats$Et[1]
Rnew[1]<-Current_dayStats$Rt[1]

E_I<-0
I_R<-0

### SIMULATION STARTS HERE
for(i in 1:49)
{
  newinfections<-rbinom(n=Snew[i],size=1,prob=(1-MLE^Inew[i]))
  sumofnew_infec[i]<-sum(newinfections)
  Snew[i+1]<-Snew[i]-sumofnew_infec[i]
    if(i>0)
    {  
      E_I<-sum(sumofnew_infec[i])
      #E_I<-0
      I_R<-sum(Enew[i])
    }
    else
    {
      E_I<-sumofnew_infec[i]
      I_R<-sum(Enew[i])
    }
    Enew[i+1]<-Enew[i]-sumofnew_infec[i]+E_I
    Inew[i+1]<-Inew[i]+E_I-I_R
    Rnew[i+1]<-I_R+Rnew[i]
}
sumofnew_infec
Snew
Enew
Inew
Rnew
```

I want to store the results in a matrix, for example

S = S_{i,j}

where S_{i,j} = S[i] = susceptibles on day i, in the jth simulation.

Then I can find the average of S_{i,1}, S_{i,2}, ..., S_{i,100} which would be the average model prediction for the number of susceptibles on day i. And finally I can plot all these averages to see the average susceptible process. This is the whole, I am trying to use replicate, creating above a function, but thats not working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

EDIT :
I created the simulation in a function.

```
> do_once()
 [1] 180 176 173 167 155 136 105  57  19   3   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
[24]   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
[47]   0   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save data in matrix for multiple simulation, here is an example

```
dayNum <- 50
simNum <- 100
S <- matrix(dayNum*simNum,nrow = dayNum)
for (j in 1:simNum) {
  for (i in 1:dayNum) {
    S[i,j] <- runif(1)
  }
}
```

---

When you want to calculate the average of `S` over simulations, you can use `rowMeans`

```
rowMeans(S)
```

---

**Edit**

```
sumofnew_infec_out <- c()
Snew_out <- c()
Enew_out <- c()
Inew_out <- c()
Rnew_out <- c()
for (k in 1:100) {
  for (i in 1:49)
  {
    newinfections <- rbinom(n = Snew[i], size = 1, prob = (1 - MLE^Inew[i]))
    sumofnew_infec[i] <- sum(newinfections)
    Snew[i + 1] <- Snew[i] - sumofnew_infec[i]
    if (i > 0) {
      E_I <- sum(sumofnew_infec[i])
      # E_I<-0
      I_R <- sum(Enew[i])
    }
    else {
      E_I <- sumofnew_infec[i]
      I_R <- sum(Enew[i])
    }
    Enew[i + 1] <- Enew[i] - sumofnew_infec[i] + E_I
    Inew[i + 1] <- Inew[i] + E_I - I_R
    Rnew[i + 1] <- I_R + Rnew[i]
  }
sumofnew_infec_out <- cbind(sumofnew_infec_out,sumofnew_infec)
Snew_out <- cbind(Snew_out,Snew)
Enew_out <- cbind(Enew_out,Enew)
Inew_out <- cbind(Inew_out,Inew)
Rnew_out <- cbind(Rnew_out,Rnew)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, how can I fit my simulation on run if. Also, dim of S is 50,1 with values 5000 all over it.

Comment: @VarshaGupta I guess you can add another `for` loop to wrap your existing `for` loop for simulations. Note that you should initialize your `S` as a matrix such that you can save the data into `S[i,j]`

Comment: I am not sure, what I have is a vector of length 50 itself in simulation output, but I just want to store it in a row wise manner, as its give length mismatch error.

Comment: @VarshaGupta If you have `S` (assuming it is a vector of length 50) in each simulation, you can use `Sout <- cbind(Sout,S)` to construct the matrix, where you should initialize `Sout` like `Sout <- c()`

Comment: I am not familiar with it, could you please update that for me, in your answer. I am adding the output of my simulation in question.

Comment: @VarshaGupta see my edit, but I am not sure if it works since I cannot check that without data

Comment: I am sorry, this doesnt work, I shared a function, do_once in EDIT, which gets that output, but I cant use it your edit, as k is not there, and I just want to fit it all with you last matrix building code.

Comment: @VarshaGupta Sorry that I cannot help further